# Differences : get dressed/ dress up/ be dressed/ get dressed up to the nines?

Tags: word-choice

Which one is correct?

(1) It's a formal occasion so we'll have to **get dressed to the nines** - no jeans and pullovers this time.

(2) It's a formal occasion so we'll have to **dress up to the nines** - no jeans and pullovers this time.

(3) It's a formal occasion so we'll have to **get dressed up to the nines** - no jeans and pullovers this time.

CAMBRIDGE DICTIONARY - 
dressed (up) to the nines (informal)
=to be wearing fashionable or formal clothes for a special occasion

I wonder whether the phrase " get dressed up" actually exists or not because I can't find any native material including it except some examples written by my country-non-native English speaking country.

Comment: _Get dressed_ usually refers to the physical process of putting clothes on - _I was getting dressed when the telephone rang._ The verb _dress_ can mean this, but it can also include the selection of one's outfit, as in _dress to the nines. Dress up_  means either to dress formally or to wear some kind of costume - _the little girl was dressed up as a fairy._  I don't think _get dressed up_ is particularly idiomatic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it naively conflates three different usages ("get dressed", "dressed up" and "dressed to the nines") each of which can be understood using commonly-available references.

Comment: Personally, “I don’t like the leading ***get*** or the ***up***:  “It’s a formal occasion so we’ll have to dress to the nines” or “... be dressed to the nines”.  It’s a question of describing the result or the action we’ll have to take.  I prefer to describe to resultant state in this instance.

Comment: Collins dictionary has "You don't have to get dressed up for this party." as an example sentence https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/dressed-up

Answer (score 1):

"Dressed to the nines" is the ubiquitous modern construction I find in a newspaper search. But it seems to have originated in the 1850s or earlier and wavered for decades, often adding "up".

"A blind partizan would now have recommended that the vote should be reversed, as the ministerial men--dress up to the nines--had come tumbling in from Government House." - Hamilton Spectator (Canada), 29 Jul 1858.

"Tom Thumb and his bride held a levee at the Continental Hotel in Philadelphia. Tom was dressed 'to the nines,' in black broadcloth, and ware a diamond ring and patent leather boots." Pittsfield Sun (MA), 19 Feb 1863.

"How do you supposed, Mr Editor, one of our modern churches, dressed to the nines, with its numberless evergreen arches and festoons would have seemed to the eyes of the pious Cotton Mather...?" - Wyandotte Commercial Gazette (KS) 18 Jan 1868.

"Miss Claremont, who impersonates the Miller's daughter, is a saucily pretty or prettily saucy little lady who is dressed up 'to the nines.'" The Conservative via The Era (London, England), 6 Apr 1873.

"He viewed that; it was about half full of a dowdy, Irish-looking woman, 'dressed up' to the nines, but...." Buck County Gazette (PA), 22 Jul 1875.

"Pete was brought into court by a deputy, and was, as usual, dressed up to the nines in a swell suit and flashy collar and necktie and scarf-pin..." Inter Ocean (Chicago, IL), 28 Mar 1879.

Answer (score 0):

All three are acceptable.

I prefer "up to the nines" but simply "to the nines" is attested in [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/(up)_to_the_nines).

Since the *up* can be part of the phrase "up to the nines" the question of whether "get dressed up" exists or not could be ignored, as the *up* is not related to the dressing directly in that interpretation.

However, since that can be ambiguous*, I searched [Google books](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22get+dressed+up%22) for "get dressed up" and found thousands of hits from native speakers. A small selection:

- "it was time to get dressed up in our game gear" — ["Pee Wee Football to the Pros: A Mother's Perspective"](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=DCzr6D7_eBIC&pg=PA68&dq=%22get+dressed+up%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjcgZKIu8TmAhWJZMAKHcUBDm44WhDoAQhvMAk#v=onepage&q=%22get%20dressed%20up%22&f=false), Lucinda Fowler.
- "My girls loved to get dressed up" — ["Encore Performance: How One Woman's Passion Helped a Town Tap Into Happiness"](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=LyL5RJWKzcMC&pg=PT60&dq=%22get+dressed+up%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjcgZKIu8TmAhWJZMAKHcUBDm44WhDoAQhmMAg#v=onepage&q=%22get%20dressed%20up%22&f=false), Vicki G. Riordan, Brian Riordan.
- "insisting though that we still get dressed up." — ["Sunday You Learn How to Box: A Novel"](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=9xoe8UW9yVwC&pg=PA24&dq=%22get+dressed+up%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjcgZKIu8TmAhWJZMAKHcUBDm44WhDoAQgoMAA#v=onepage&q=%22get%20dressed%20up%22&f=false),  Bil Wright.

*It could be "**get dressed** up to the nines" or "**get dressed up** to the nines"

Comment: The last two examples in your answer are identical except for the preposition 'up' in the first which is not in bold. Is the emphasis supposed to show where the ambiguity lies?

Comment: @Mari-LouA yes it is

Comment: OK so you're saying that the idiom can be used with *up* "up to the nines" or be used with the PHRASAL expression "get dressed up". However, I'm not sure I would call it ambiguity. What Would be the difference in *meaning*?

Comment: It's about emphasis. "up to the nines" and "to the nines" essentially mean the same thing, but "getting dressed" and "getting dressed up" do not. It's the difference between saying "I'm going to make myself look nice" and "I'm going to make my self look nice, really nice".

Comment: But how is that difference in emphasis conveyed in writing if the words used are totally identical?  Do you see what I'm driving at?  Also, if you remove "up" from "**get dressed to the nines**" the meaning of paying extra attention to one's appearance and clothes for a special event doesn't  change. The difference in meaning (and emphasis) is apparent between *get dressed* and *get dressed up*.

Comment: I don't get what you're driving at. What does this have to do with writing?

Comment: I would've upvoted were it not for the part where you claim "get dressed up to the nines"  can be ambiguous. I thought I was missing something in the answer but I see I wasn't. For me there is no ambiguity in the two last examples whether  spoken or written because they are identical.

Answer (score 0):

"dress up to the nines", while perfectly idiomatic, is still less frequently used than the simpler phrase "dress up". (Younger speakers might also be less likely to use this idiom -- but it'll be hard to find data on this.)

"dress up" is neutral and can be used in both informal and formal contexts.

"get dressed up" is possible. It depends on the context.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, **up** is an emphatic adverb – it implies “completely.” Adverbs are not essential and can be omitted with little or no change to the meaning o the sentence.

**To get** = to become

**To get**, in this sense, when used with a past participle, can form a type of passive, although the participle is probably adjectival:

We ate the food -> The food got eaten [by us] -> the food became eaten -> the food was eaten.

(Compare The food was heated -> the food became hot/heated)